Realtime Plot Using Plotly In a Single Figure Object
I wrote the following code (minimally working example) that uses plotly to show candlestick charts in real-time.
It works great.
However, the only issue I have is that every time I receive new data there will be a new plotly figure and over time I will end up having many opened figures, which I don't want.
Is there any way to plot everything in a single plot and update the same figure with new data?
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
import random

ohlc_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["timestamp", "open", "high", "low", "close", "volume"])
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=[], open=[], high=[], low=[], close=[])])
fig.update_layout(title=f'Live Candlestick Chart', xaxis_title='Time', yaxis_title='Price')

def update_live_chart(fig, df):
    fig.update_traces(x=df['timestamp'], open=df['open'], high=df['high'], low=df['low'], close=df['close'])


while True:

    sleep(1)
    new_data = pd.DataFrame([{
        "timestamp": datetime.now().timestamp(),
        "open": random.randint(100, 110),
        "high": random.randint(100, 110),
        "low": random.randint(100, 110),
        "close": random.randint(100, 110),
        "volume": random.randint(100, 110)
    }])

    ohlc_data = pd.concat([ohlc_data, new_data], ignore_index=True)
    ohlc_data = ohlc_data.tail(100)
    update_live_chart(fig, ohlc_data)

    fig.show()



There is currently no way to do that with plotly.py alone, calling fig.show() will open a new tab every time. You could use Dash (also made by the Plotly team), which allows to build rich layouts and update components (not only plotly figures, any components) using dash callbacks. Another way would be to do that in javascript, using plotly.js which provides functions for updating figures as well.

Here is a minimal dash example and here is a full fledged web trader interface, which might go in the desired direction.
